# PDFTron Webviewer Open PDF with a user password

Tags: javascript, pdftron

I am trying to use the PDFTron WebViewer within a Blazor application to open a PDF with a user password.

I would like to do this without a user dialog but I am can't figure out how to.

I am calling the initWebView function with the url path to the passworded pdf. This downloads the document and displays a prompt to enter the password. I am able to enter the password manually and the document opens successfully. However, I would like to bypass this prompt by supplying the password as an argument, thus opening the passworded document without any intervention from the user.

```
var wvInstance;

window.webviewerFunctions = {
    initWebViewer: function (url) {
        const viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
        WebViewer({
            path: 'lib',
            initialDoc: url,
            fullAPI: true
        }, viewerElement).then(instance => {
            wvInstance = instance;
        })
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the [`DocumentViewer#loadDocument` API](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/Core.DocumentViewer.html#loadDocument) with the `password` option I think.